# Java Boolean Input Error Checking

Tags: java, boolean, user-input, error-checking

So I'm trying to get the user to input their answer as a boolean and then error check that, but that doesn't seem to be working.  Am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this?  I had thought about doing it where the input is a string and just checking it against two other strings that I assign to "true" and "false," but my while loop:

```
while (!continueGame.equalsIgnoreCase(answerTrue) && !continueGame.equalsIgnoreCase(answerFalse)) {    
        System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (true/false)");
        continueGame = keyboard.nextBoolean();
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Didn't work either.  I'm fairly certain it's something to do with my not's, but I'm not sure why.  Anyway, below is my method for error checking using booleans instead of strings.  The string version was basically the same way but just modified for strings.

```
public static boolean continueGame() {
    boolean continueGame;

    System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (true/false)\n");
    continueGame = keyboard.nextBoolean();
    System.out.println();

    while (continueGame != true && continueGame != false) {    
        System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (true/false)");
        continueGame = keyboard.nextBoolean();
        System.out.println();
    }
    if (continueGame) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("We accept your surrender.");
        return false;
    }

} //End continueGame method
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly isn't working?  Also, to keep your code more DRY, I would recommend a post-check loop and removing the block before the loop.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244832/java-loop-not-resetting/) and see if it helps you. You're doing something strange with continueGame != true && continueGame != false because how can a boolean value be "not true AND not false?" A boolean is either true or false, and by extension, either not true or not false.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I'll just swap the way your loop works, so breaking condition can be reached.

```
import java.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loop
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   boolean continueGame=true;
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (true/false)\n");
   continueGame = keyboard.nextBoolean();

   while (continueGame) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (true/false)");
    continueGame = keyboard.nextBoolean();
    if(!continueGame)
    {
        System.out.println("We accept your surrender.");
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this accomplishes what OP wanted.  I think he wants to keep asking for true/false if the user enters something different, but I want him to confirm.

Answer (score -1):

```
while(true) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (true/false)");

    if(keyboard.hasNextBoolean()){
        continueGame = keyboard.nextBoolean();
        System.out.println();
        break;
    }

}
```

This will prompt the user for a true/false indefinitely until they enter a valid boolean. Then it will break out of the loop and you can continue with the rest of your code.

Comment: You should declare the Scanner keyboard outside the loop.  Creating it each time through is both wasteful and could cause undesired behavior in some cases.